# Unresolved reference to CustomAction:Cleanup in WiX

Tags: c#, wix

When processing an MSI file from Installshield with dark.exe it generates a file with multiple instances of the error when built from Visual Studio 2013:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'CustomAction:CleanUp'
```

Part of the wxs file is:

```
          <Dialog Id="SetupCompleteSuccess" X="50" Y="50" Width="374" Height="266" Title="[ProductName] - InstallShield Wizard" NoMinimize="yes">
            <Control Id="OK" Type="PushButton" X="230" Y="243" Width="66" Height="17" Text="&amp;Finish" TabSkip="no" Default="yes" Cancel="yes">
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CleanUp">ISSCRIPTRUNNING="1"</Publish>
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchProgramFileFromSetupCompleteSuccess">LAUNCHPROGRAM And PROGRAMFILETOLAUNCHATEND &lt;&gt; "" And NOT Installed</Publish>
                <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Exit">1</Publish>
                <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="ShowMsiLog">MsiLogFileLocation And (ISSHOWMSILOG="1") And NOT ISENABLEDWUSFINISHDIALOG</Publish>
            </Control>
```

Looking at the MSI file with ORCA, in table CustomAction contains an entry for LaunchProgramFileFromSetupCompleteSuccess (which does not throw an error) and no entry for Cleanup, so dark.exe is behaving consistently as it creates a set of CustomActions as follows:

```
       <CustomAction Id="ISPreventDowngrade" Error="[IS_PREVENT_DOWNGRADE_EXIT]" />
    <CustomAction Id="ISRunSetupTypeAddLocalEvent" BinaryKey="ISExpHlp.dll" DllEntry="RunSetupTypeAddLocalEvent" />
    <CustomAction Id="ISSelfRegisterCosting" BinaryKey="ISSELFREG.DLL" DllEntry="ISSelfRegisterCosting" />
    <CustomAction Id="ISSelfRegisterFiles" BinaryKey="ISSELFREG.DLL" DllEntry="ISSelfRegisterFiles" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
    <CustomAction Id="ISSelfRegisterFinalize" BinaryKey="ISSELFREG.DLL" DllEntry="ISSelfRegisterFinalize" />
    <CustomAction Id="ISUnSelfRegisterFiles" BinaryKey="ISSELFREG.DLL" DllEntry="ISUnSelfRegisterFiles" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
    <CustomAction Id="SetARPINSTALLLOCATION" Property="ARPINSTALLLOCATION" Value="[INSTALLDIR]" />
    <CustomAction Id="SetAllUsersProfileNT" Property="ALLUSERSPROFILE" Value="[%SystemRoot]\Profiles\All Users" />
    <CustomAction Id="setAllUsersProfile2K" Property="ALLUSERSPROFILE" Value="[%ALLUSERSPROFILE]" />
    <CustomAction Id="setUserProfileNT" Property="USERPROFILE" Value="[%USERPROFILE]" />
    <CustomAction Id="ShowMsiLog" Directory="SystemFolder" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]notepad.exe &quot;[MsiLogFileLocation]&quot;" Return="asyncNoWait" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchProgramFileFromSetupCompleteSuccess" BinaryKey="NewBinary19" DllEntry="LaunchProgram" />
    <CustomAction Id="ISPrint" BinaryKey="SetAllUsers.dll" DllEntry="PrintScrollableText" />
```

How should I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Find in which dll '*Cleanup*' custom action is present and add a reference

```
<Binary Id="CleanupBinary" SourceFile="Your location of the CleanUp Dll" />
<CustomAction Id="CleanUp" BinaryKey="CleanupBinary" DllEntry="Your cleanup custom action name" />
```

Comment: How do I identify the presence of a custom action in a dll? Which dlls should I be looking at?

Comment: Is the installer created by you. If so, then I guess you can get the source code of the custom actions.  If it not created by you, use *' dark -x ./ YourInstaller.msi '*  which will create the *' Binary '* folder. Check inside that folder whether any file contains *' CleanUp '* . If there is no CleanUp, then I am sorry, I can't be much helpful.

Comment: There is a Binary folder which contains 19 files with the name NewBinaryN, where N ranges from 1 to 19. files 1-18 appear to be image .NewBinary19 is a dll, but it appears to be used to launch programs. The entry in the CustomAction table in the msi file is  `LaunchProgramFileFromSetupCompleteSuccess 1 NewBinary19 LaunchProgram`

Comment: Hi Simon, I am trying to figure out how the installer is created. Out of curiosity, have you tried to install using the installer..  Is it successful?

Comment: If it try and process the file using the Wix cmd  tools Candle and Light, Candle generates a .wixobj file OK but light reports the same problem as Visual Studio - Unresolved reference to Symbol, so I guess that is what is generating the Unresolved Symbol messages from Visual Studio.